# Remove text between ( and ) in js variable

Tags: javascript, variables, text

I have got this variable: `var alma = 'Ez itt (alma)';`
I would like to get this for output `Ez itt`

How can I do it?

:-) It's like substr in php, but this is not what I need. This variable was an example... I have more variables, about 100-200 and different lenght.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this,

```
var alma = 'Ez itt (alma)';
var output = alma.substring( 0, alma.indexOf("(")-1 );
alert(output);
```

***Update***

---

If you just need to replace values inside the brackets and get the rest of string, try this

```
var output = alma.replace(/ *\([^)]*\) */g, "");
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use regexes:

```
var result = alma.replace(/\s*\([^)]*\)\s*/g, "");
```

with `g` being used if you want to remove all parenthesised texts (remove `g` if you want to remove just the first occurrence). This will not work on embedded parentheses, i.e., it will not work on "bla (bla (bla))", but can be fixed to do so if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [substring](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substring.asp) method.

```
var output = alma.substring( 0, 6 );
```

Comment: :-) It's like substr in php, but this is not what I need. This variable was an example... `I have more variables, about 100-200 and different lenght. `